# Shell script or Perl to scrape log files for data processing?

Tags: perl, bash

I am trying to decide on which language to use to write a script that will "scrape" log files from a server application. The general algorithm of the script will be something like (still hashing out all of the little details of course):

```
1. Search for any line that contains (ACK_STRING, PARTIAL_FILL_STRING, or COMPLETE_FILL_STRING) and not AUTO_HEDGER_STRING
2. For each result
{
    Extract time, order ID, symbol, status, theo, price from line

    Get intermediate edge value
        If buy, edge = (theo - price)
        Else, edge = (price - theo)

    If order ID not found in order ID -> orderquoteinfo structure
    {
        Add (edge * qty of order) to total edge
    }

    Add edge to total edge received
        Add (edge * qty filled) to total edge received

    Store info in order ID -> orderquoteinfo structure
}

3.
For each order ID -> orderquoteinfo structure
{
    Print results in CSV format

    Time, Order ID, Symbol, Status, B/S, Qty, Price, Theo, Edge
}

4. Print total edge missed
    Print total edge - total edge received

5. Print total edge received
```

So, essentially, I am wanting to use a data structure similar to a map in C++ or an associative array in Perl to persist information I scrape from each line of a log file. I'm not as familiar with shell scripting but trying to see what language would make sense here. The server application I am pulling the logs from reside on a Linux server (and very little chance it will ever be ported to another platform anytime soon). So the portability factor of Perl doesn't come into play in my mind.

For me, I am just more familiar with writing Perl scripts than shell scripts. However, I would like to write a shell script if it makes more sense to do so here. This script would run as a scheduled task once a day (give or take). Basically, the script just serves as a way to easily grab metrics data out of log files. I use the term "scraping" because I will be searching for specific strings in the log files that are the least likely to change but still have that risk.

So, should I write a shell script or use Perl? What makes more sense? Does it matter here?

Answer (score 3):

#### Perl

---

Actually, I was tempted to say: "*Shell or Perl?*  Easy, use Ruby", which is why subjective questions like this tend to get closed.

But a hopeless cause is somehow intriguing so I will attempt a serious answer: you can certainly write complicated things as shell code, but, compared to a real language like Perl, the effort is greater and the results are inferior.

Use Perl.

Answer (score 2):

Perl is really what you need. After all PERL means "Practical Extraction and Reporting Language".

from wikipedia : "Perl was originally developed by Larry Wall in 1987 as a general-purpose Unix scripting language to **make report processing easier**". So it was the first goal of Perl to process this kind of datas. And it does perfectly.

With a shell script it will be too painfull rather than Perl and regular expression to handle your log.

Comment: Note that "Practical Extraction and Reporting Language" is a [backronym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backronym).

Answer (score 1):

This is part of a script that i use for realtime-ish monitoring of my webserver logs, and i'm sure it can easily be rewritten to do what you need. It should be noted that `File::Tail` might be a better choice if you're only monitoring one logfile from the script.

This code wraps the read in two while loops, where the inner while-loop checks each file for new lines, while the outter while-loop checks for new files. You might want to use something else than `while (1) { }` so that it actually moves on, tho.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Tail::Multi;

while (1)
{
        my $reloadtime = time();

        my $file=File::Tail::Multi->new(
                Function        =>      \&parseline,
                LastRun_File    =>      '/var/autoblock.runtrack',
                Files           =>      ["/var/log/www/*/access.log"],
                RemoveDuplicate =>      0,
                NumLines        =>      0,
        );

        while (1)
        {
                $file->read;
                sleep 2;
        }
        sleep 2;
}

sub parseline()
{
        my $ref = shift;
        foreach ( @{$ref})
        {
         # Do stuff with each line here. The line is stored in $_
        }
}
```